# open in remote terminal showing wrong user

Tags: virtual-machine, vpn, ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-20.04, nautilus

My VM: Ubuntu 20.04

VPN VM: Ubuntu 18.04

I'm accessing a vm via a vpn using another vm, i got in successfully and now i'm using the built-in Ubuntu file explorer to access the vpn vmfiles using sftp, that works ok. My problem is when I right-click on the file explorer and try to use `Open in Remote Terminal` it opens a new terminal that says `wrongUser@xxx.xx.xxx.xxx's password:`  where `wrongUser` is my vm user and not the vpn vm user, so I can't use it. Thanks!

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what "built-in Ubuntu file explorer" you are using; possibly `nautilus`. I don't know how you are using it; possibly by opening `sftp://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx` and supplying the right username and password to a pop-up window.

Specify the right username in the address in the first place:

```
sftp://rightUser@xxx.xx.xxx.xxx
```

Alternatively (or if the above doesn't work in your unspecified file explorer) edit your `~/.ssh/config` (on the client, i.e. where `nautilus` or whatever is about to use SSH; create the file if needed) and specify `rightUser` as the default user for the `xxx.xx.xxx.xxx` host:

```
Host xxx.xx.xxx.xxx
User rightUser
```

See [`man 5 ssh_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#User) for details. Now SSH connections to `xxx.xx.xxx.xxx` with no username explicitly specified will use the `rightUser` instead of your local username.

Comment: Yes, it's `nautilus` ` sftp://user@xxx.xx.xxx.xxx` worked! Thanks!